# nvidia opengl framebuffer object forces vsync on

Tags: c, opengl, nvidia, framebuffer, quake

Basically I implemented gamma correction into a q3 based game to get rid of the annoying [SetDeviceGammaRamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd372194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm using GL_EXT_framebuffer_object for a post process vertex shader.
It works pretty fine except that it has some weird behavior on nvidia gpus:
It forces vsync to be enabled except when it is explicitly disabled in the control panel. **If I use the standard control panel's settings and the framebuffer is enabled vsync is forced, but if I remove the framebuffer it goes back to normal behavior.**

- wglSwapIntervalEXT does nothing
- I tested it on an nvidia mobile GPU, someone could reproduce it on a desktop GPU
- I also tested an integrated intel gpu and two different amd gpu's and all of them didn't have the issue.

initialization: (unrelevant i guess)

```
// ouned: gamma correction
const char *g_GammaVertexShaderARB = {
    "void main(void)" "\n"
    "{" "\n"
        "gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;" "\n"
        "gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;"  "\n"
    "}"
};

const char *g_GammaFragmentShaderARB = {
    "uniform sampler2D sceneBuffer;" "\n"
    "uniform float gamma;" "\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)" "\n"
    "{" "\n"
        "vec2 uv = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;" "\n"
        "vec3 color = texture2D(sceneBuffer, uv).rgb;" "\n"
        "if (uv.x<0.50)" "\n"
            "gl_FragColor.rgb = pow(color, vec3(1.0 / 1.5));" "\n"
        "else" "\n"
            "gl_FragColor.rgb = color;" "\n"
        "gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;" "\n"
    "}"
};

    tr.m_hVShader = qglCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
    qglShaderSourceARB(tr.m_hVShader, 1, (const GLcharARB **)&g_GammaVertexShaderARB, NULL);
    qglCompileShaderARB(tr.m_hVShader);

    if (qglGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        ri.Printf(PRINT_ERROR, "Failed compiling gamma vertrex shader\n");
    }

    tr.m_hFShader = qglCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
    qglShaderSourceARB(tr.m_hFShader, 1, (const GLcharARB **)&g_GammaFragmentShaderARB, NULL);


    qglCompileShaderARB(tr.m_hFShader);

    if (qglGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        ri.Printf(PRINT_ERROR, "Failed compiling gamma fragment shader\n");
    }

    tr.gammaProgram = qglCreateProgramObjectARB();
    qglAttachObjectARB(tr.gammaProgram, tr.m_hVShader);
    qglAttachObjectARB(tr.gammaProgram, tr.m_hFShader);
    qglLinkProgramARB(tr.gammaProgram);

    if (qglGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        ri.Printf(PRINT_ERROR, "Failed linking shaders\n");
    }

    qglUseProgramObjectARB(tr.gammaProgram);

    tr.gammaUniformLoc = qglGetUniformLocationARB(tr.gammaProgram, "gamma");
    tr.gammaSceneBufferLoc = qglGetUniformLocationARB(tr.gammaProgram, "sceneBuffer");

    qglValidateProgramARB(tr.gammaProgram);
    qglUseProgramObjectARB(0);

    // framebuffer object
    tr.gammaFramebuffer = 0;
    qglGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &tr.gammaFramebuffer);
    qglBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, tr.gammaFramebuffer);

    // depth buffer
    tr.gammaRenderDepthBuffer = 0;
    qglGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &tr.gammaRenderDepthBuffer);
    qglBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, tr.gammaRenderDepthBuffer);
    qglRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight);

    tr.gammaRenderTarget = 0;
    qglGenTextures(1, &tr.gammaRenderTarget);
    qglBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tr.gammaRenderTarget);
    qglTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    qglGenerateMipmapEXT(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    qglBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    qglFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tr.gammaRenderTarget, 0);
    qglFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, tr.gammaRenderDepthBuffer);

    qglBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

On the beginning of a frame:

```
    qglBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, tr.gammaFramebuffer);
    qglBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, tr.gammaRenderDepthBuffer);
    qglDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
```

on the end of a frame:

```
    qglBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
    qglBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    if (!backEnd.projection2D) {
        qglViewport(0, 0, glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight);
        qglScissor(0, 0, glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight);
        qglMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        qglLoadIdentity();
        qglOrtho(0, glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight, 0, 0, 1);
        qglMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        qglLoadIdentity();

        GL_State(GLS_DEPTHTEST_DISABLE);
    }

    qglUseProgramObjectARB(tr.gammaProgram);
    qglEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    qglUniform1iARB(tr.gammaSceneBufferLoc, 0);

    qglColor3f(tr.identityLight, tr.identityLight, tr.identityLight);
    qglActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0);
    qglBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tr.gammaRenderTarget);

    qglBegin(GL_QUADS);
    qglTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    qglVertex2f(0, 0);
    qglTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    qglVertex2f(glConfig.vidWidth, 0);
    qglTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    qglVertex2f(glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight);
    qglTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    qglVertex2f(0, glConfig.vidHeight);
    qglEnd();

    qglUseProgramObjectARB(0);
```

So, what else can cause vsync to be enabled?

Comment: Might it have something to do with using GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT calls instead of the non-EXT version, which has been around for quite a while now? I remember i had a problem with that once - not related to vsync, but showing that there might be a difference between EXT and non-EXT... other than that, no idea.

Comment: I will try it, but the reason why I choosed the extension was that it has slightly wider support. framebuffers are in the core since 3.0 and e.g. vmware only seems to support 2.1 (in which I'm testing)

Comment: @ouned: The ARB extension and EXT extension are almost identical, all of the constants (e.g. `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`) are the same in both extensions. The only major difference comes down to a few extra validation rules in the EXT extension that were removed from the ARB extension / core GL3. Realistically, I think anything that supports the EXT extension will support the ARB extension so long as the end-user has updated their drivers.